# How can I prevent calabash-android from pushing the apk for every feature file?

Tags: calabash-android

When I run calabash-android, it appears to push the apk to the device for every feature file.  I would prefer to push the apk once and reuse it, as each push takes about half a second, and I expect eventually to have enough feature files for this to matter.  I'd be happy with a solution which doesn't push the apk at all and to push it myself in an earlier step.

Comment: Is it pushing the app each time or just restarting the app?  My tests restart between each step by default but I have always had to control the installations.

Comment: I got the same problem. Tried to start by command line with RESET_BETWEEN_SCENARIOS=0 doesnt work. Tried to uncomment some lines in the .rb files doesnt work. 

This is an absolute fail...

Answer (score 0):

Is it pushing the app each time or just restarting the app?  My tests restart between each step by default but I have always had to control the installations.

I deal with the installation by tagging the scenarios that require a reinstall and looking for the tag in my before hook.

If it is the restarting between scenarios that you want to control then you can use the RESET_BETWEEN_SCENARIOS setting.

Comment: Actually it is pushing the app each time.  I've found where it does this, in the default app_installation_hooks.rb.  When the issue becomes a problem, I will simply rework this script.

Comment: Ahh, I remember seeing that file now.  I ended up cutting most of it out when I needed to add in support for multiple OS's as it got a bit noisy and I didn't need a lot of it.  Glad you found your solution!